# Do dormant databases impact server performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, php, memory

On our web server, my team has been creating new databases in MySQL to manage backups.  They simply create new database_DATE and copy over our live site.  Which made me think today...  Can having a database (no possibility of ever being used) impact performance (guessing memory) of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1:  An extra table or database will eventually be pushed out of cache.  It is harmless.  Cure (but not worth doing): restart mysqld.

Case 2:  The 'system' is building thousands of tables and/or databases.  Each table/database involves at least one entry in the containing OS directory.  As this directory gets fuller, the OS operations to access files/directories (hence tables/databases) slows down.  Granted, it takes thousands, maybe tens of thousands of such entries before the impact is painful, but there is impact.  Cure: Stop building so many tables/databases, and `DROP` the excess.

Case 3:  Someone or something does `SHOW DATABASES` or `SHOW TABLES` or `SELECT ... FROM information_schema ...` and it is sensitive to the number of tables/databases.  These actions will load stuff into memory, possibly blowing out some cache (such as `table_open_cache`)  Cure:  Same as for both cases 1 and 2.

Bottom line:  When there are hundreds of these databases, tell them to clean up their act!  (Until then, don't worry.)

Comment: Would you say that backing up a Wordpress site with 800 posts and 15K users/data - so pretty small - times about 10 backups - can have any noticeable effect on performance given we are on a very fast server with 8 GB of RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Memory is used by dormant databases

I mentioned this in the following posts over the years

- `Nov 13, 2015` : [#1041 - Out of memory issue in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120999/1041-out-of-memory-issue-in-mysql/121033#121033)
- `Apr 22, 2014` : [Do Inactive MySQL Databases Consume Memory?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63621/do-inactive-mysql-databases-consume-memory/63650#63650)
- `Apr 21, 2014` : [Adding new tables -- memory usage increases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63591/adding-new-tables-memory-usage-increases/63593#63593)

Lots of tables ? Lots of columns ? Of course, that is less memory for mysqld to work with.

[You just asked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141871/do-dormant-databases-impact-server-performance/141874#comment268756_141874)

> Is there a way to ensure a database is using no memory?

If you never access a table, no data or index pages will ever touch the [InnoDB Buffer Pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), the [MyISAM Key Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size), or any session's [read_buffer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_buffer_size) or [read_rnd_buffer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_rnd_buffer_size).

Notwithstanding, having too many tables with lots of columns will result in nothing more that a lot of dormant information_schema memory. Neither the number of rows in each table nor the size of any of the tables matter.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure a database is using no memory?